# python 3 - count in array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, count

I have input array like this in python 3.
input: [[4 1 -1 4][2 0 5 1 ] [1 6 2 -1][7 3 0 -2]]
output1:[[1] [1] [1] [2]]
output2:3

output1:count number of elements <=0 and display in the output
output2:display the index which has maximum value in output1
How to get this output 1 and output2?
Even if we could get the output2 directly that is awesome.

Comment: You should not ask questions like this here. You should post the code you are working with and ask for advise on why it is not working or how to improve it. Otherwise, you will only get down votes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're after

```
def output1(lst):
    return [ [sum(1 for i in inner if i <= 0)] for inner in lst ]

def output2(lst):
    return max(enumerate(lst), key = lambda tup: tup[1])[0]

>>> x = output1([[4, 1, -1, 4],[2, 0, 5, 1],[1, 6, 2, -1],[7, 3, 0, -2]])
>>> x
[[1], [1], [1], [2]]
>>> output2(x)
3
```